# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{(2-\cos(x))^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given that
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a-\cos(x)}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}},\,a>1 $$

How do i solve $$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(2-\cos(x))^2} $$

I tried using partial fractions but could not make it work, im thinking it must end with some variation of $ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a-\cos(x)}$, or else the tip would be useless.

Comment: Feynman's trick: consider the derivative of both sides of the first identity with respect to $a$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint : Let $$f(a) =\int_{0}^π\frac{dx}{a-cosx}$$

Now try taking derivative of this integral w.r.t. $a$.

$$f'(a)=-\int_{0}^π\frac{dx}{(a-cosx)^2}=\frac{-a\pi}{(a^2-1)^{3/2}}$$

Do you get any idea to proceed?

Comment: +1 for this creative way to solve the problem (however you just changed an integral problem with another one right?)

Comment: I think this exactly how we were meant to solve the problem, we have learned about Feynmans technique "differentiating under the integral sign"

Comment: @Jose Thanks! BTW, where is another integral problem? We just need to evaluate $f'(2)$, i.e. we have to put $a=2$ in the rightmost expression. There by giving us the answer to be $\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{27}}$.

Comment: why is the last integral easier to solve than the first one? I get how you got the last integral

Comment: @GuyFsone We don't have to solve anything in this integral obtained in the last step. Just put $a=2$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I meant how do you compute $\int_{0}^π\frac{dx}{(a-cosx)^2}$

Comment: @GuyFsone Look, we don't need to evaluate anymore. We have already done, by using the given information. $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a-\cos(x)}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$ Differentiate w.r.t $a$ both the sides. Did you get it?

Comment: Ok I understand now thanks

Comment: @Guy Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\frac{d} {dx} \frac {\sin x} {a-\cos x} =\frac{a\cos x-1} {(a-\cos x) ^2} $$ and hence $$\int\frac{dx} {(a-\cos x) ^2}=-\frac{\sin x} {a-\cos x}-a\int\frac{dx} {a-\cos x} +a^2\int\frac{dx}{(a-\cos x) ^2}$$ or $$(a^2-1)\int\frac{dx}{(a-\cos x) ^2}=\frac{\sin x} {a-\cos x} +a\int\frac{dx} {a-\cos x} $$ and using the limits $0,\pi$ we get $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(a-\cos x) ^2}=\frac{\pi a} {(a^2-1)^{3/2}} $$

Answer (score 1):

**just a hint**

Put $$x=2\arctan (t) .$$

then

$$2-\cos (x)=\frac {1+3t^2}{1+t^2} $$

and
$$dx=\frac {2dt}{1+t^2}. $$
The integral becomes

$$2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac {1+t^2}{(1+3t^2)^2}dt $$

now, use partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Just Hint :

$Tan x/2 = t $ limit from 0 to $infinity$

$0.5*(Sec x/2)^2 dx = dt$

Now convert $$cosx = (1- (tan x/2)^2)/(1+ (tan x/2)^2)$$